# Rails + Vue: Accessing instance variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, vue.js

I have a simple view, but `Purchase` `belongs to :client`.  Therefore to access the `purchases` I need to provide a `client_id`.  :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var purchases = new Vue({
    el: '#purchases',
    data: {
      purchases: []
    },
    ready: function() {
      var that;
      that = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'clients/' + CLIENT_ID + '/purchases.json', // problem
        success: function(res) {
          console.log(res)
          that.purchases = res;
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

How do I access the `client_id` in the ajax request?  I tried `<%= @client.id %>` but it get the error `undefined method`id' for nil:NilClass`.

**How do I pass that variable?**

Comment: The question is where you have defined `CLIENT_ID` ?

Comment: It's an Ruby instance variable in the view / controller and is defined in the page params

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question is you cant access an instance variable directly in a js function. This is because js is a client side language which only runs in your browser and ruby/rails is a server side language.

The only way you can access the variable in js is by passing it as an html data. For eg as a hidden field in your corresponding html.erb file.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag('client_id', @client_id) %>
```

and accessing it as

```
client_id: $('#client_id').val()
```

in the js file.